# How to read from a csv file saved offline in iOS app .

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have dragged and dropped a .csv file in my iOS app which I want to read . I know the method to read from the file but I don't know how to figure out the path of it .

So, how can I figure out the path ?

Comment: is your file showing in the app bundle ?

Comment: Yes, and now I am also able to read it. Problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pathForResource:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"fileExtension"];
```